# Surface Area from a definite integral equation

Tags: calculus, functions, definite-integrals, area

To find a **surface area** we need a **function**, but how to find the **surface area** if you are given a ***definite integral question***?

Comment: Could you please be more specific and give a concrete example of what you are asking for?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good
question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: I've been given a question in the exam to find the surface area and the question was a definite integral equation?

Comment: How do I obtain the original function from an integral?

Comment: State the problem.